# Компилирую приложение в Release

Tags: c#

The command "if Release == Release (
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ORC\JSFunctions\debug
call MinifyScript.bat
)" exited with code 1

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151402/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-command-exited-with-code-1 тут посмотрите, может найдете ответ, тк вы не указали подробно сложно ответить

Comment: Собственно, вопроса то в вопросе и нет.

Comment: Могли ведь больше информации, больше текста предоставить, чтоб все поняли что не так, верно? Если вам такой вопрос зададут, что будете делать? Вот тут тоже самое. Что касается приложенного текста, то у вас в проекте скорей всего установлено правило после успешной сборки, которое запускает `MinifyScript.bat`, который в свою очередь дал ошибку, ну а какую ошибку, тут надо изучать логи, которые вам студия любезно предоставляет. Так что, либо убирайте этот `MinifyScript.bat`, либо исправляйте его, чтоб тот успешно выполнялся, другого не дано.